# Mysql on Ubuntu: ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've installed mysql server on my Ubuntu 16.04 using this command:

```
user@samariter-ubuntu:~/dev$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I left the "root" pass blank. It went fine, no objections. However, when I try to start it, it refuses:

```
user@samariter-ubuntu:~/dev$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sasa'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I must start it with sudo. Why is that? How can I solve it?

Comment: Who told you that MySQL is started with `mysql`? If you installed MySQL via `apt-get` then it's a service and it's available with `service mysql`. Using `service mysql status` will tell you the status of the daemon, and there are a few more commands such as `stop`, `start`, `restart` etc. Why did you type that you must start it with sudo? You already used `sudo apt-get...`. What is the actual problem you're having? MySQL's installed and it works.

Comment: You're right, I expressed myself very bad, but the snippet is correct. Apparently, the service was started by apt-get. The problem is that command mysql returns this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo service mysql-server` : Install mysql server as a service. It downloads mysql server latest version available from apt repository.

`sudo service mysql status` : Check the status of your service

`sudo service mysql start` : start mysql server

`sudo service mysql stop` : stop mysql server

`sudo service mysql restart` : restart mysql service

To connect mysql server from mysql built in client, use the below command

```
$> mysql -u root -p
```

If your root password is empty, just press enter again. You will be prompted to

```
mysql >
```

Comment: The last command prompts for password, but returns error: ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: that means, your password is not empty

Comment: follow this "https://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/" and better reset your password

Comment: then try with new password

Comment: I followed the instruction, but it failed again on the step 3: sasa@samariter-ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables

Comment: did you install mysql-client ?

Comment: what's the output for this ?
"telnet 127.0.0.1 3306"

Comment: I've just executed those two commands, posted up in the question. Then comes the error. Now I've tried to remove my-sql from the system and install it again using the same command, but it looks that something from the first installation was not removed - it never prompts for the root's password?!

Comment: ye may be something wrong with first install, just remove it and try again,
sudo apt-get uninstall mysql-server
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server...
and then install again

Comment: Yes, all fine, mysql -u root -p works now, the installation was corrupt. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

First of all here you are not starting mysql. And this error is coming directly from mysql ubuntu has nothing in this. Your error says that `mysql` is already started but the the current user by which you have logged in Ubuntu is not found in the mysql's user table.
Typeing simple mysql means you want to log into mysql with current OS user that is sasa in your case.
try : `mysql -uroot`
Here root means mysql's root user not OS' root.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately, it returns ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: Looks like you set a password for root and now you have forgot it. follow this link to reset your root password : https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords specially the part :  Recover MySQL root password, try resetting it and then give it an another try.